# Hosting server program written in Java

Tags: java, sockets, hosting

I wrote a messenger server program using Java and TCP sockets; are there any hosting services that accept TCP connections? or do I have to rewrite the program using web-sockets written in another language?

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine, Amazon EC2, and any general web host that allows one to run custom software rather than a predetermined set of server software can run such application servers.

Comment: What port does the Java program have to listen on with the Google Compute Engine?

Comment: You can listen on whatever port you want. It's your VM to do with as you please. The only trick is how to route external traffic to a particular host/port if you want to call this endpoint externally. With HTTP there is a standard, default port. With your own application, you'll have to figure out how the port is specified or selected.